# jQuery selector wont read load() content on document.ready()?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, load, jplayer

I know you all probably thinking that on() is the solution and I hope so, however I've tried and can't figure it out. I've got jQuery function that uses ('audio') to create playlist for jPlayer. The music is divided into categories and posts I want the player load songs from posts when browsing categories. so it goes like:

```
var songsforjplayer = [];   
    $('body').append('<div id="newsongs" style=""></div>');
    $('#newsongs').load('http://sample_post audio');

    var singlesonglist = $('audio'); //selector doesn't recognize freshly load audio so it doesnt include them inplaylist
    singlesonglist.each(function(i){
        var source = $(this).attr('src');
        songsforjplayer[i]= {
            title:  $('track',this).attr('src'),
            oga: source,
        }

        });
```

I've tried using on() with various event types - the fact is, there is no event - it should be triggered when the category page is ready but it doesn't make the selector to catch new audio tags.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Of course not.  It hasn't loaded yet.  `load()` is async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you load new audio, you will have to rerun this code to refresh the playlist with whatever new audio in in the page and you will have to run the code after the .load() has completed by using a completion function on the .load() method.  One way to do that is like this:

```
var songsforjplayer;

function updatePlaylist() {
    songsforjplayer = [];
    var singlesonglist = $('audio');
    singlesonglist.each(function() {
        var source = $(this).attr('src');
        songsforjplayer.push({
            title:  $('track',this).attr('src'),
            oga: source
        });
    });
}

$('body').append('<div id="newsongs" style=""></div>');
$('#newsongs').load('http://sample_post audio', updatePlaylist);
```

Keep in mind the `.load()` is asynchronous.  It takes awhile to finish and it runs in the background while your other code is running.  The code right after the call to `.load()` runs BEFORE the `.load()` is completed.  The ONLY way to guarantee that a piece of code runs AFTER the `.load()` is done is by using a completion function like I've shown in the code above.

I also removed an extra comma after `oga: source` that would be an error in older versions of IE.

Comment: but the new audio (#newsongs) loads on pageload so after document.ready(). and the 'audio' selector is used after i render #newsongs with new audio. 

its literally:


   `     (function($){
        (jQuery)(document).ready(function(){

       var songsforjplayer = []; 
... `

any ideas ?

Comment: But `.load()` is asynchronous and can finish after `document.ready()` so you have to update the song list after the `.load()` is done.  See the clarifications in my answer.

Comment: I defined updatePlaylist() before document.ready and i call is after load() that is in document.ready(): 
`$('#newsongs').load('http://localhost/houseofgood.info/50/mashup-rework-remix-mix/ audio', updatePlaylist());`

I even put new new JplayerPaylist() piece of code in updatePlaylist() and it creates it. it does create playlist from the songs in the content, but doesn't append 'audio' from #newsongs. #newsongs are visible at the bottom and can be played. I'm loosing my mind here. it's still the 'audio' selector somehow.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the `.load()` is asynchronous.  It takes awhile to finish and the ONLY way you can run code after it is done loading is by using a completion function like I've shown in my answer.  Code right after the `.load()` will run before it is completed.  Did you try to code in my answer?  Not much more I can say.

Comment: so sorry!! I actually tried your code and got the asynchronous part, HOWEVER i used updatePlaylist() and it didn't work. I believed you assumed I would write `function(){updateplaylist()});` in '$('newsongs').load() as callback; 
I'm such a nOOb. 
thanks again!

Comment: @KamilZawadzki - it will work exactly as I have it in my answer (if you look closely to how I have it).  If you used `updatePlaylist()` with the parens, that was wrong and is not what I have in my answer - it should have just been `updatePlaylist` without the parens.  You need to pass just a function reference - you don't want to execute the function immediately.

Comment: right again and thanks again! 
it works perfectly - now I'm gonna focus on passing the load url so the playlist changes depending on the category.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that load() is an ajax method. AJAX by definition is asynchronous so your player code is running before load is completed. You need to call your plugin from within load success callback

```
var songsforjplayer = [];
$('body').append('<div id="newsongs" style=""></div>');
$('#newsongs').load(url, function() {
    /* inisde the success callback the new html exists and can now attach events */
    var singlesonglist = $('audio'); //selector doesn't recognize freshly load audio so it doesnt include them inplaylist
    singlesonglist.each(function(i) {
        var source = $(this).attr('src');
        songsforjplayer[i] = {
            title: $('track', this).attr('src'),
            oga: source,
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I defined updatePlaylist() before document.ready and i call is after load() that is in document.ready(): 
`$('#newsongs').load('http://localhost/houseofgood.info/50/mashup-rework-remix-mix/ audio', updatePlaylist());`

I even put new new JplayerPaylist() piece of code in updatePlaylist() and it creates it. it does create playlist from the songs in the content, but doesn't append 'audio' from #newsongs. #newsongs are visible at the bottom and can be played. I'm loosing my mind here. it's still the 'audio' selector somehow.

Comment: now you are introducing new information and functions that doesn't match the code you provided... not mucch can help with there